# How can I convert YMD LDAP timestamps to date time in Java?

Tags: java, timestamp, ldap, unix-timestamp

For instance I have the date as: 20171208181856.0Z and I want to convert it into date time format using java. I don't seem to find any working solutions for it.

Comment: Is there always exactly one decimal after the decimal point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) using input format and parse it into [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) or [OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html)

```
String dateTime = "20171208181856.0Z";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss.SX");

OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateTime,formatter);

System.out.println(offsetDateTime);
```

Comment: Good Answer. But `OffsetDateTime` would be more appropriate for a UTC value (the `Z`) than `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: I suggest deleting the `ZonedDateTime` code altogether. No advantage to it. Showing both is confusing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, really appreciate your quick help. It solves my issue half way, although I get the correct date, the time is a bit weird: "2017-12-08T18:18:56Z".

Comment: Why it is weird ? and what is your expected output ? @RiddhimaBhalerao

Comment: @Deadpool, It should look like this: 2017-12-08 18:18:56 GMT, something like this, any timezone is fine. I don't want the T and Z in the datetime. I can remove it by string operations but then I just wanted to try with Java time and date packages. I tried with zone but it is not working for some reason.